# python: Is there a way to input varied arguments, such as having 1,2, or 3 arguments without running into a type error?

Tags: python, list, sockets, arguments, typeerror

First time posting on stack overflow, so give me all the advice when it comes to asking the correct question and whatnot.
I'm currently using the socket module in python for a school project to create a "command prompt/virtual router interface", that can setup listening "addresses" (we can use ports to keep it simple), router advertisements, turning on the virtual interfaces, etc.
The biggest hurdle I have at the moment is figuring out to have the command prompt accept varied arguments sizes without running into a type error.
The goal (at first) is to have the command prompt accept single, double, and triple arguments, instead of the constant two I already have; what my code does already is take the input, split it into different arguments, and then uses them.
I don't know how to begin to try to change this. I tried to make default values whenever there isn't three arguments but that was to no avail.
The code starts like a command line prompt without the ">", ready to accept any input. Then I type in a "command", such as listenport 200, which then the code runs and then listens to port 200 (code not shown, since it is not applicable to the problem). However, sometimes I need three arguments such as remoteHost, which needs the remoteHost and remotePort at the same time.
Instead of constantly putting in a third value that won't do anything, I wanted to try to have it accept varied responses. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
while 1:
    try:
        message, address = clientSocket.recvfrom(8192) # Buffer size is 8192. Change as needed.
        if message:
            print (address, "> ", message.decode())
    except:
        pass
 
    input = getLine();
    if(input != False):
        port = 0 
        #port2 = 0 
        print ("input is: ", input)
        delimitedInput = input.split(' ')
        print (delimitedInput)
        (command, port) = delimitedInput
        #(command, port, port2) = delimitedInput
        print ("Command: ", command)
        print ("number: ", port)
        #print ("number: ", port2)
```

Comment: Just check `len(delimitedInput)` to see how many command line arguments you got, and then branch based on that.

Comment: Oh! So I should separate my commands based on the len(delimitedInput) and have the one arguments on one branch, two arguments on another branch, and three arguments on the third branch?

Comment: Yes, just `numC = len(delimitedInput)`, and then `if numC > 1`, etc. How you do the branching depends on your logic.